# numerical gradient of an array

Tags: list-manipulation, vector-calculus

I have 2D arrays of numeric data and I would like to calculate the vector gradient of these arrays.

I would like to achieve something like the 'gradient' function of MatLab:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html

In my understanding the 'Grad' function of Mathematica works on expressions of functions. I had a look at other functions but I didn't seem to find anything appropriate. I tried searching on the stackexchange, I apologize if this is trivial or a duplicate, I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you need `Differences`.

Comment: The two-sided approximation matlab uses (except for the endpoints) is `ListCorrelate[{-1, 0, 1}/2, data]`.

Comment: Have you looked at GradientFilter or GradientOrientationFilter? You can find commands where you know part of the name by using wlldcard searches, in this case, ?*Gradient*

Comment: @Coolwater it is not clear, what is the corresponding command "gradient" in Mathematica?